# Custom numbering scheme for document libraries

Tags: document-library, event-handlers

I need to create an event handler for a document library that will give custom Id's to documents and folders in it. The top folders will be prefixed with capital letters, folders and documents in second level folders will be prefixed with numbers, etc.

I want to know if something like this is developed by someone before so I can start using it immediately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running SharePoint 2010 you can enable document ID feature to get functionality that resembles what you mention.

You can even roll your own Document ID provider with custom syntax

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/04/13/sp-2010-sharepoint-server-2010-creating-your-custom-document-id-provider.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521589.aspx

Comment: Not so different from event receivers but I think Document ID providers are more aligned with SharePoint development in general.